# Why does this type-safe wrapper around Objects.equals not fail when called with different argument types?

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to implement a helper function that behaves like `Objects.equals(a, b)`, except that it can only be called with two objects of the same type. So my idea was to create a generic wrapper `<T> strictEquals(T a, T b)` where each argument has the same type `T`.

My implementation looks like shown below, but to my surprise the function can still be called with different argument types without getting a compiler error. Is this a misunderstanding of how Java generics work?

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {
    public static <T> boolean strictEquals(T a, T b) {
        return Objects.equals(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(strictEquals("abc", 5));  // Why does this not produce a compiler error?
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd have to check the spec to be sure, but I *assume* it's equivalent to calling `strictEquals((Object) "abc", (Object) 5)`.

Comment: (Your method doesn't say the arguments have to be of the same type - it says that both arguments have to be convertible to `T`.)

Comment: You need to declare T's upper bound or it's just recognized as `Object`

Comment: "type-safe wrapper around Objects.equals" There is nothing type-unsafe about `Object.equals()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Why does this not produce a compiler error?
System.out.println(strictEquals("abc", 5));
```

When the type parameter `T` of `strictEquals` gets inferred by the compiler it tries to find a type that makes the types check out. The result is that it infers a common super-type of `Integer` and `String`, which turns out to be `Object`. (It might also be `Comparable` or `Serializable` or something like that.)

Since both arguments are subtypes to `Object` the method type-checks fine.

One way to make the compiler detect a type error is to provide an explicit type argument to `strictEquals`:

```
// Error: not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer)
System.out.println(Main.<String>strictEquals("abc", 5));
```

---

You can force the user to provide a type by adding a class object parameter:

```
System.out.println(Main.strictEquals(String.class, "abc", 5));

public static <T> boolean strictEquals(Class<T> compareAsType, T a, T b) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(compareAsType);
    return Objects.equals(a, b);
}
```

---

Another work-around might be rely on the fact that types are invariant in their type arguments. For example, only compare boxes of values, like this:

```
Box<String> b1 = new Box<>("abc");
Box<Integer> b2 = new Box<>(5);
// Error: not applicable for the arguments (Box<String>, Box<Integer>)
System.out.println(Main.strictEqualsBoxed(b1, b2));

public static <T> boolean strictEqualsBoxed(Box<T> a, Box<T> b) {
    return Objects.equals(a, b);
}

class Box<T> {
    T value;
    public Box(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

But it's still easy to circumvent:

```
// No error
System.out.println(Main.strictEqualsBoxed(new Box<>("abc"), new Box<>(5)));
```

Maybe their is some other kind of arcane genetics wizardry to make a better solution...? I don't think so, but I will now embark on a quest to find out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Java will resolve `T` to the most generic base type that both parameters inherit from, in this case `Object`.

I don't believe there is any way to use generics for the problem you're trying to solve. Generics are [erased at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). Note that it's very common for overridden implementations of `equals` to check (at runtime, not compile-time) that the two compared values have the same type.

Your best alternative would be to create many implementations of `strictEquals` that take in parameters of the same primitive type, for example:

```java
public static boolean strictEquals(int a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}

public static boolean strictEquals(String a, String b) {
    return Objects.equals(a, b);
}
```

Comment: *"Generics are erased at runtime."* I don't think that's relevant here, because this is about a compile time type check. Erasure is often the source of problems in other situations, though!